# ternary operator in strongly typed HTML view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, strongly-typed-view

I have a bit field in database which I want to display on my HTML view as "Yes" or "No"
How can I use ternary(?:) operator to do this?

Here is what I have, but it displays "No" for all the records.

```
<%= Html.Encode( Convert.ToString(item.IsValid) == "True" ? "Yes" : "No")%>
```

Comment: What type is `item.IsValid`?

Comment: If `item.IsValid` is already a boolean, you shouldn't be converting it to a string.

Comment: Why are you html-encoding a value that can never possibly have a value that needs encoding?

Comment: @Lloyd it is of type "Bit"

Comment: That's the DB type, what type is `IsValid` in .NET?

Comment: @jmoerdyk Not converting it to string gives error: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: @user793468 That's because you're doing a string comparison.

Comment: @Lloyd its "boolean" in .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to fix this.

1) Seems how IsValid is already a boolean, just take the value

```
<%= item.IsValid ? "Yes" : "No"%>
```

2) If you insist on converting it, compare it using Equals with the StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase flag

```
<%= Convert.ToString(item.IsValid).Equals("True", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "Yes" : "No"%>
```

Comment: Get error: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'
with your first method. And error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
with your second method

Comment: Have you confirmed IsValid has a value?  What is the definition in the model?

Comment: My mistake, checked wrong table for the value. It worked! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

or even simpler -

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.IsValid ? "Yes" : "No") %>
```

Comment: Get error: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: apparently, your item.IsValid is string; not bool! If it were bool, computer wouldn't complain because it wouldn't need to convert!

Answer (score 2):

Normally you can use below :

```
<%: item.IsValid ? "Yes" : "No" %>
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: Right, no need to encode if you know the string is just " yes" or "no"

Comment: Get error: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Answer (score 1):

Why are you converting to string? This should just work assuming `IsValid` is a bool:

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.IsValid) == true ? "Yes" : "No")%>
```

If it's a string you'd want something like:

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.IsValid.ToLower() == "true" ? "Yes" : "No")%>
```